Why do I only get the right laplace transform by using convolution
I'm sorry for what's probably quite a basic question. I don't understand why calculating the one-sided Laplace transform of the following integral
$$
f(t)= \int\limits_0^t g(u)g(t-u) \operatorname{d}\!u
$$
one gets $L[f(t)]=G(s)^2$, result which is not hard to obtain if by thinking $f(t)$ as the convolution $g(t)\ast g(t)$, while trying to calculate it by noting that
$$
\begin{align}
L[f'(t)] &=L[h(t)]\\
\text{and} & \\
L[f(t)]s -f(0) &=L[h(t)]
\end{align}
$$
where $h(t)$ is meant to be everything inside of the integral at $t$ and $-f(0)$ should give me zero, fails.
I ended up getting $\frac{G(s)g(0)}s$ instead of the correct result, I'm having a hard time seeing where I made the mistake.

$f'(t)$ is not $h(u)=g(u)g(t-u)$ at $t=u$.
